# Getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after SSL installation in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis, https

We are currently migrating our site from http to https, so after SSL installation to IIS, we created a redirect rule to redirect from http to https. Because if we not add permanent redirect rule 301 and tried to hit urls with https site automatically redirects to http.

Application contains few master pages and most of the asp controls.
The rule which i have written is correctly working for new page which i added to application but it is not working for existing old pages. In case of old pages it shows error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

```
  <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Reason for occurring ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error?

Comment: May be this url good for you https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/

Comment: hello @MetinAtalay thanks for your reply but i have already checked those possibilities to solve my issue

Comment: You need to use tools like Fiddler/failed request tracing to see further into those old pages. Very likely the authors of those pages decided to always redirect to HTTP, which goes against your rewrite rule. If that's the case, you cannot merely use rewrite to achieve your goals, but have to modify those old pages.

Comment: try to add the condition <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />  instead of  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />. or try this rule: `<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"   redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
</rules>`

Comment: also try to clear the browser cache, cookie, and history.

Comment: I tried with your solution too @JalpaPanchal , and also tried with adding new aspx page with same content as per old aspx page, after this also it perfectly worked for new page but not working for the old one.

Comment: did you try to delete the history and cache?